# Firebase for web-distinguish between visitors of different documents of a website

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-analytics

I have already used Firebase for my android apps in order to get some statistics and track events. Now for the first time I want to use Firebase for my website to get some simple statistics of visits and clicks. While setting up my project, Firebase generated some code to be pasted after `<body>` tag.

since I have multiple HTML documents in different URLs, I have to paste those codes in all my documents. Will Firebase distinguish between the visitors of each page or they will be all summed up together? I couldn't find the answer in their [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?authuser=0#add-sdks-initialize).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand completely but if you are talking strictly about the analytics code then it will just send all of that data into the analytics account which you will then be able to filter by url and see the visitor data for a given page.

Comment: in my firebase dashboard, in `add filter` section, I can see only the following options: `platform`, `stream`, `audience name`, `user property` and `signed in status`. could you please tell me where exactly I can filter by url?